# Cannot be resolved to a type.. (Java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm fairly new to programming in general so any help would be appreciated.  Im coding in java with eclipse and I am getting this error on the last line "EmployeeAction cannot be resolved to a type" and I already imported java.util.ArrayList. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

EDIT: Thanks All. I was following a [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/)

It provided the code for [EmployeeDetails.java](http://code.google.com/p/androidtutorial/source/browse/trunk/%20androidtutorial/EmployeeDirectory6/src/samples/employeedirectory/EmployeeDetails.java) here which I guess is wrong:

```
package samples.employeedirectory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EmployeeDetails extends ListActivity {

protected TextView employeeNameText;
protected TextView titleText;
protected ArrayList<EmployeeAction> actions;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment.So writing as answer

You need to have a class name EmployeeAction
Import the class or create it as an inner class

```
  class EmployeeAction{
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `actions` is an `ArrayList` of `EmployeeAction`, you should also import `EmployeeAction` as it looks like a user defined type.

Answer (score 0):

you might not have imported class `EmployeeAction.class`

Answer (score 0):

fomr the look of your code, EmployeeAction is a class. Have you defined this class? Have you defined it in the same package? If not, you will need to import it.

Answer (score -1):

Import your model class to your list activity class